# Why do the balls behave the way they do?

Tags: python, pygame

I want each ball to move independently. I think the problem has something to do with them all having the same velocity, but I don't know why they do or if that's even the problem. Also, why does the right portion of the screen behave the way it does? I want the balls to be able to move all over the screen properly.

```
import sys
import pygame
import random

screen_size = (screen_x, screen_y) = (640, 480)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

size = {"width": 10, "height": 10}
velocity = {"x": {"mag": random.randint(3,7), "dir": random.randrange(-1,2,2)}, "y": {"mag": random.randint(3,7), "dir": random.randrange(-1,2,2)}}


class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, size, position, velocity):
        self.size = size
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

    def update(self):
        self.position["x"] += (self.velocity["x"]["mag"] * self.velocity["x"]["dir"])
        self.position["y"] += (self.velocity["y"]["mag"] * self.velocity["y"]["dir"])

        if self.position["x"] <= 0 or self.position["x"] >= screen_y:
            self.velocity["x"]["dir"] *= -1

        if self.position["y"] <= 0 or self.position["y"] >= screen_y:
            self.velocity["y"]["dir"] *= -1

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.position["x"], self.position["y"], size["width"], size["height"])

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    fps = 30
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    balls = []

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                (x, y) = event.pos
                position = {"x": x, "y": y}
                new_ball = Ball(size, position, velocity)
                balls.append(new_ball)

        for ball in balls:
            ball.update()

        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        for ball in balls:
            ball.display()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the right of the screen is due to a typo in this line in `update()`:

```
if self.position["x"] <= 0 or self.position["x"] >= screen_y:
                                                         # ^ should be x
```

This prevents your `Ball`s from entering the rightmost `640 - 480 == 160` pixels of `screen`.

The balls all behave the same because you only call `randint` to get random values once, when you first create `velocity`. Try moving the `randint` call into `__init__`, e.g.

```
def __init__(self, size, position, velocity=None):
    if velocity is None:
        velocity = {"x": {"mag": random.randint(3,7), 
                          "dir": random.randrange(-1,2,2)}, 
                    "y": {"mag": random.randint(3,7), 
                          "dir": random.randrange(-1,2,2)}}
    self.size = size
    self.position = position
    self.velocity = velocity
    self.color = (255, 255, 255)
```

This allows you to provide a `velocity` or be assigned a random one. In `main()`, you can then call:

```
balls.append(Ball(size, position))
```

to add a new `Ball` at the mouse `position` with random `velocity`.

On a side-note, you could simplify your `position` and `velocity` attributes to `(x, y)` tuples, as used in `pygame`, rather than your `dict` structures, i.e.:

```
velocity == (velocity['x']['mag'] * velocity['x']['dir'],
             velocity['y']['mag'] * velocity['y']['dir'])

position == (position['x'], position['y'])
```

Then your call in `main()` could be:

```
balls.append(Ball(size, event.pos))
```