# How do I make my ball bounce?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make my "ball" (`player1`) "bounce" when it moves to 10% of the size of the screen. Right now, it just stops accelerating.

I'm pretty sure I have to do something with `self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"]` and `self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"]`. I thought that by setting `self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"]` and `self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"]` equal to zero, it'd stop moving completely, but it just stops accelerating. I also thought that by multiplying `self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"]` and `self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"]` by -1, I'd "flip" the direction in which it was moving, but doing that didn't seem to affect anything.

When I say I want to make it "bounce", I mean I want it to stop immediately, reverse directions, and go in whatever direction the player is pressing. For example, if you held s from the beginning, I'd want it to just look like you'd dropped a ball.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 30


class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x_mag = 0
        self.y_mag = 0
        self.x_dir = 0
        self.y_dir = 0
        self.vel = {"x_vel":
                        {"x_mag": self.x_mag, "x_dir": self.x_dir},
                    "y_vel":
                        {"y_mag": self.y_mag, "y_dir": self.y_dir}}
        self.x_pos = (screen_width / 2)
        self.y_pos = (screen_height / 2)
        self.pos = {"x_pos": self.x_pos, "y_pos": self.y_pos}
        self.size = (10, 10)

    def move_right(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 1
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 0

        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] += 5
        self.pos["x_pos"] += (self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] * self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"])

    def move_left(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 1
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 0

        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] -= 5
        self.pos["x_pos"] += (self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] * self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"])

    def move_up(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 0
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 1

        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] -= 5
        self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])

    def move_down(self):
        self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] = 0
        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] = 1

        self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] += 5
        self.pos["y_pos"] += (self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] * self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"])

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move_up()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.move_left()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move_down()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.move_right()

        if self.pos["x_pos"] <= (screen_width * .1) or self.pos["x_pos"] >= (screen_width * .9):
            self.vel["x_vel"]["x_mag"] = 0
            self.vel["x_vel"]["x_dir"] *= -1

        if self.pos["y_pos"] <= (screen_height * .1) or self.pos["y_pos"] >= (screen_height * .9):
            self.vel["y_vel"]["y_mag"] = 0
            self.vel["y_vel"]["y_dir"] *= -1

        self.character = pygame.Rect((self.pos["x_pos"], self.pos["y_pos"]), self.size)

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 255, 255), self.character)


def main():
    player1 = Character(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        player1.move()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        player1.display()

        pygame.display.update(screen_rect)
        clock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know anything about PyGame, but it seems to me that when you set your velocity vector's magnitude to 0, you're saying to stop moving.  Try not touching the magnitude, and just flipping the direction.

Comment: @cHao I tried that and the ball just kept accelerating off the screen. Just flipping the direction without changing the magnitude makes sense to me, though. I'm not doing something right with the direction, but I don't know what.

Comment: Well...it doesn't really help that in your `move` functions, you're using the magnitude as which way to go, whereas when you're checking for bounces, you use the direction.  Is there a particular reason you are using two numbers in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had this right [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953986/pygame-why-do-the-balls-behave-the-way-they-do)! You should reverse the direction of the `velocity`, but leave it with the same magnitude.

Again, I would just use a 2-tuple, where each value is the product of magnitude and direction for the appropriate axis. Then reversing is as simple as:

```
# bounce off top
self.velocity = (self.velocity[0], -1 * self.velocity[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to store `x_mag` and `x_dir` separately - they could be stored in a single variable `x_vel` where the sign represents the direction. You also have two separate copies of `x_mag` - `self.x_mag` and `self.vel['x_vel']['x_mag']`. This is bad practice as changing one will not change the other. As `jonrsharpe` suggests, I would just use a `tuple` or `list` for the velocity and position:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.velocity = [0, 0]
        self.position = [screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2]

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.velocity[1] += 5 # move up
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.velocity[0] -= 5 # move left
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.velocity[1] -= 5 # move down
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.velocity[0] += 5 # move right

        self.position[0] += self.velocity[0]
        self.position[1] += self.velocity[1]

        if self.position[1] <= (screen_height * .1) or self.position[1] >= (screen_width * .9):
            self.velocity[0] *= -1
```

Comment: I agree. It is better to keep things simple as possible :)